# My Dwarf has been resting for ages, how do I get him to wake up?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Currently one of my dwarfs is sleeping in the hospital after I removed his bed and he decided to sleep there instead. He has been resting for over a year now and i'm not sure how to wake him up.

The other thing is that under the health screen he is marked for a Diagnosis request, I have a chief medical dwarf available but nothing seems to be happening there either.

Comment: deconstruct his bed

Comment: He's dead Jim...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Chief Medical Dwarf isn't doing diagnosis tasks, he's probably too busy. Diagnosis is an annoyingly low-priority job, so the CMD would rather do basically anything else, even carting stuff from place to place around the fortress. I would turn off ALL other labors the CMD has turned on (except for diagnosis) until he gets off his butt and does his job. Of course, he might take the opportunity to go "on break" for a couple weeks, then take a drink for a while, then eat his seasonal meal, but that happens sometimes.

Of course, since you mentioned your injured dwarf has been Resting for over a year, most likely he is permanently disabled. Most dwarves will heal anything healable within 4-6 months, so if he hasn't healed yet, he probably ain't gonna. I recommend a topical application of magma; I find this tends to cure anything that refuses to heal in some other manner.

Comment: @aslum I should write a bot that answers every dwarf fortress tagged question with "Use Magma".

Comment: @ Shard: Do it!

Comment: @astum but the CAPTCHAs!

Comment: Zelda 2 once said "If all else fails, use fire". Magma is like fire...

Comment: It's Liquid Fire.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get him back into a bed in the hospital, and make sure you Chief Medical Dwarf has the Diagnose labor enabled.

In some versions, perhaps including the current one, injury is buggy and some dwarves never wake up.

Comment: Well, the most recent versions of DF should have fixed that bug. Older versions though, yes.

Comment: @Raven I'll have to work toward an injury in my current fort ...

Comment: Build an upward staircase on the surface, then lead a bit of floor away from it, and order the floor tile connecting the staircase and the rest of the floor removed. 9 times out of 10 the dorf that takes the labor will stand on the soon-to-be-unsupported bit of floor and land on his head.

Comment: @Shadur DF is replete with ways to cause injury ...

Comment: "injury is buggy and some dwarves never wake up."  

who says that's a bug?